# Random Always Generates The Same Number

Tags: c#, random

I'm using Random class to generate any random integer number but it always returns the same number

```
static Random rand = new Random();
public static int GetOrderID()
{           
     return rand.Next(Math.Abs(int.MinValue + 1), int.MaxValue);
}
```

notice that the random class is static and generated outside the function

Comment: Hint: what is the value of `Math.Abs(int.MinValue + 1)`? How does it compare to `int.MaxValue`? Now that `Next(x, x)` will return `x`, the answer should be relatively clear. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What would you expect if

```
Math.Abs(int.MinValue + 1)
```

is equal to

```
int.MaxValue
```

so your range contains one number only.

Answer (score 2):

It´s simple: Calling `Math.Abs` will delete the sign from the number. As the minimum integer is `-2,147,483,648` its absolute value (incremented by `1`) is `2,147,483,647`  which equals the absolute value for `int.MaxValue`.

So when calling `Math.Abs(int.MinValue + 1), int.MaxValue` you allways get `2,147,483,647`as return-value, right?

If you need any arbitrary int you may however use `rand.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue)` without using `Math.Abs`. For any non-negative integer-number you can use the overload without any parameters.